# Save 2 very large strings for comparison

Tags: php

For my website check tool, I want to store the body of a page to compare it to other pages. I only need to know if there are pages with exactly the same body.

I'm storing the body in a MySQL table, and when storing the entire string, it just takes up too much space and isn't scalable.

I'm looking for a way to store the string just to compare it to other strings. Is there a way to do that without having to store the whole thing?

Comment: store them in separate files ?

Comment: Yep, I think this approach of saving snapshots in static files would be your best bet !

Comment: If you only want to check if the pages are exactly the same why not calculate a checksum (MD5, SHA)? Comparing or storing checksum is much easier.

Comment: Use of hashes is good idea, but pages need to be normalized before hashing e.g. space differences should be removed. This approach needs intense testing before actual use

Comment: @Rick you may also need to think about "exactly same body" definition. Do you mean whole page should be same or e.g. just its text contents. It will lead to very different approaches

Comment: @Flying: it's really the whole text. Often the same content is available on different URLs, so the whole body will be the same